# To_SQL not recognizing chunksize for Snowflake

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I currently am working with a dataframe that is producing an error that there are too many rows for Snowflake to import at one time.

I have looked around, and I did find that to_sql has an option to flag for chunksize.

However, when I put in a number for this, I get this error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100038 (22018): Numeric value 'unknown' is not recognized

This is my code, which I think is pretty straightforward and I don't see any obvious errors:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('snowflake://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SNOWFLAKE_LINK/DATABASE/SCHEMA?warehouse=WAREHOUSE&role=ROLE', connect_args = {'connect_timeout': 10}, echo=False)
df2.to_sql('TABLE', con=engine, schema='PUBLIC', index = False, if_exists = 'append', method= 'multi', chunksize=16384)
```

Is this a quirk with Snowflake when it comes to this or do I need to use something like write_pandas to import my data?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out.

This is the code that finally worked:

```
df2.to_sql('TABLENAME', con=cursor,  index = False, if_exists = 'append', method=pd_writer)
```

pd_writer seemed to be the method that I needed to get over 16K rows into Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below code in case if you want to use chunks

```
   import pandas as pd

def fetch_pandas_sqlalchemy(sql):
    rows = 0
    for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, chunksize=50000):
        rows += chunk.shape[0]
    print(rows)
```